Create top-level domain cookie inside subdomain not working (Express behind IIS rewrite)
I want to set a top-level domain cookie (i.e. domain:".example.com") from sub.example.com.
I know I have to set the "domain" attribute like so:
const app = express();
app.get("/set", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("name", "express", { domain: '.example.com', path:'/', httpOnly:true, secure:true, sameSite:'lax' }).send("cookie sety");
});

But when I access the page from sub.example.com (Browser, Postman, ...) it always says "domain: .sub.example.com".
The website is running on Windows-Server, IIS 10, Node 20.
IIS is configured for bindings: sub.example.com, example.com (both 80 and 443).
Rewrite-Configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>                                       
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3528/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>

I have no idea, at what point the domain get's "rewritten". I checked the web, stack-exchange and copilot. Couldn't find any clue.

Try disabling the URL rewrite rules as a test to see if that configures cookies correctly at the top level domain? And when setting secure=true, cookie will only work with https.

@XudongPeng I tried both, http and https with nearly all possible permutations of the other flags besides "domain". Nothing changes, it's always ".sub.example.com" and never ".example.com" what is returned. I can't disable this only(!) rule, because it is what's connecting my app to IIS.

Can you please clarify, what "it says" / "is returned" actually means? What exactly are you looking at? The storage information in browser dev tools? The Set-Cookie header received by the client? Something else?

You can try to clear browser cache and test again, by the way, what the mean of it is what's connecting my app to IIS? When you deploy the application in IIS only, you cannot access the site without using a reverse proxy? If possible, please provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem.

@C3roe looking at the set-cookie header using DevTools or Postman. But I finally found that ARR is doing the rewrite. Thanx for looking into my problem!

@XudongPeng thanx for your input! I tried accessing my site directly using its port forwarded to the web. And as expected this time the header wasn't rewritten. Going deeper I found that IIS is using ARR and that this - by default - is rewriting all the headers. Found a solution. Thanx for your input, you helped pointing me in the right direction!

I found the solution - I'll try to be as detailed as possible, maybe it helps someone in the future.

My web Server is IIS 10 running on Microsoft Server 2019 Standard
There are no additional proxies, firewalls, ... between the web Server and the internet
IIS is used for domain-bindings (resolution), SSL and as proxy
All my websites are express/nextjs (nodejs) based running on the same machine on different ports
Inside IIS I use rewrite (see question) to relay requests the different ports

Problem in my case: In the reply-header "set cookie", the domain field is - at some point in the reply-flow - rewritten to the actual domain-name including subdomain used to access the site. Independent on what cookie-domain I send in express/nextjs.
The solution: IIS is using ARR 3.0 (Application Request Routing) - which I wasn't really aware off - with a default of "Reverse rewrite host in response header". This is not really visible inside a website configuration because it is configured on IIS-server-level - which I missed looking at.
To change this setting...

Open IIS-Manager
Click on your web Server to open configuration
Open "Application Request Routing Cache" (in IIS area)
In the right panel click on "Server Proxy Settings..."
Uncheck "Reverse rewrite host in response header"
Save Settings

Now your headers won't be rewritten for the actual user Domain when calling the site. In my case that's what I want, but keep in mind that you change the behavior of all websites! So double check that you are not creating new errors.
